# Terminology: What is a "bounded problem"?

Tags: optimization, terminology

In mathematical optimization, what does it mean if we say that a **problem** is **bounded**.

This appears (but is not defined) in a paper that I am reading and I have not found any definitions for it. 
So far, I've looked in Boyd's *Convex Optimization*, on Wikipedia, and on this site.

For example, consider Problem $(P)$:
$$
\min_x f(x) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad x \in X
$$
If we say that $(P)$ is bounded, does this mean:

- The feasible set $X$ is bounded?
- The image of the feasible set $f(X)$ is bounded?
- The image of the feasible set $f(X)$ is bounded from below?

By the way, I am reading [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-017-1191-y) article. 
This expression is found in the algorithm at the top of page 145.

Answer (score 0):

To say a problem is bounded is to say that the solution to the problem has to be special ( in simplest terms) ( special in sense that it's defined a certain way) apart from being just a general solution.

Here, there can be values of F for which it attains a minimum (global/local) which are not in the set X and they will not be considered.
In your words, in this problem, "the image of X under F" is bounded from below, or, we need the smallest element from the set of images under F of those x which belong to X.